# regular expression to match '$'

Tags: regex

How to match a string which has numbers starting with a '$' symbol?
I have used `^[0-9]*$` to match number, but when i use '$' symbol it detects end of input.
How to escape '$' in regular expression?
Expected output: **$123**

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info <- I suggest you give this a good read.

Comment: Normally, `$` has no special meaning when it is not at a position that could match the end of a string, so `^$[0-9]*$` should work, for example (it does with `grep`).  Failing that, use a backslash before the `$`.

Comment: with backslash before the `$` worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\$(\d+)
```

If you want with decimal

```
\$(\d+\.\d{2})
```

[**Regex Demo**](http://rubular.com/r/nNwOUftXdT)

Answer (score 1):

If You want to find just the '$123' try `\$\d{3}`